# How to see the vertica's procedure in DBeaver?

Tags: vertica, dbeaver

everyone

Does anyone know how to see the vertica's procedures in DBeaver?
Not use script.

[Here is I can see the objects for vertica.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TFmz.png)

[Here is I can see the objects for sql server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBgJi.png)

In sql server we can see the 'procedure' folder, but in vertica can not.

I find the last one about  this discussion.
It saild,
["DBeaver supports stored procedures/views source code view only for: MySQL, Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, Vertica, Firebird."](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1423)

Do I lost some thing need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures in Vertica are brand new.

They have become generally available with Version v11.0.1 , which just came out a few weeks ago.

DBeaver can only list, in the navigator, things that it "knows" are supported by the connected db.

I doubt you can teach new stuff to a front end in a few weeks.

And if your Vertica Version is below v11.0.1, all the worse ..

What would be worth trying, is opening a SQL window, and going:

```
SELECT * FROM v_catalog.user_procedures
procedure_name|language|procedure_arguments                                                               |schema_name
pivot         |PL/vSQL |idlist varchar, keyname varchar, valname varchar, tbname varchar, pvtbname varchar|public
```

Comment: thank your reply. I forget to say my vertica version is 11.0.1. And I know we can use user_procedures table. So we only use the way of script to get the procedure list,right?

Comment: I'd watch the developments in DBeaver versions for news, but for now - plain SQL is your friend, I think ...

Comment: You can create a feature request issue on the DBeaver GitHub for Vertica procedures. We rarely add features without specific requests from users :)